# Save dialog retrieves more then one extension

Tags: c#, dialog

How can I avoid the multiple extensions in the retrieved file name from  save dialog?
I have filtered the dialog only to Rich Text File and .doc files.

When I change the selection in the combo Box below the text Box with file name, the extension is added to the file name instead of changing the existing extension.

```
SaveFileDialog dialog= new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Title = "Please select the directory in which the document will be created.";  

// set a default file name
dialog.FileName = my_File_Name;  

// set filters
dialog.Filter = "RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf | Wordfile (*.doc)|*.doc | Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //selected folder path
    string placeToSaveDocument = Path.GetFullPath(dialog.FileName);
}
```

That is the result:

> myFileName.rtf.doc.rtf.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** Your Filter string is not proper as it has spaces after extension string `*.rtf` and `*.doc`

**Solution :** You need to eliminate the space after extension strings.Remove spaces after `*.rtf` and `*.doc`

Try This:

```
dialog.Filter = "RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf|Wordfile (*.doc)|*.doc|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Comment: @user3165438: I'm glad tobe help of you dear :)